# How to take data from Excel and do calculations?

Tags: python, excel

I want to calculate one formula.
I have 2 tables:

[image: table 1]

and

[image: table 2]

I want to take data from my tables.
I can choose different parameter from `table_2` like:
`"B5"` or `"B6"` or `"B7" ("21-35", "36-60", "61-100")`.

Also I want to assign values to cells, such as `T1=25` or `t1=12`.

Formula looks like:

```
M = (Т1*Tab2C5 + Т1*Tab2D5 + Т1*Tab2E5 + Т1*Tab2F5 + t1*Tab1C4 + t1*Tab1C5 + t1*Tab1C6 + t1*Tab1C7 + t1*Tab1C8)*10^6
```

If I take parameter `B5` from `table_2` it should calculate like:

```
M = (25*18.3+25*4.7+25*0.7+25*0.023+12*0,091387+12*0,056901+12*0,019186+12*0,14136+12*0,114861)*10^6
```

If I take parameter `B6` from `table_2` it should calculate like:

```
M =(25*23.3+25*5.8+25*1.2+25*0.029+12*0,091387+12*0,056901+12*0,019186+12*0,14136+12*0,114861)*10^6
```

Can someone help and show me how to do these sorts of things?

Comment: great question, lots of helpful screenshots, good use of syntax/highlighting

Comment: It looks like you may actually be using Google Docs instead of MS Excel. If that's the case, Google may provide an API you could use. Regardless, if you can export the data from whatever application you're using in [CSV format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), Python includes a `csv` module for reading and writing such files.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into the Openpyxl module [Openpyxl](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html)

Or [Automate the Boring stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/) which explains how to use the Openpyxl module to manipulate Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Sheets API to read and write stuff with Python, PHP, Node.js and several other languages.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts

The API allows for both entering values as is, as well as entering formulas like you asked for.

Edit: This answer is based on the assumption that you want to use Google Sheets, from your screenshots.